# Change file extension if browser is IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .htaccess

I'm looking for the best solution to dynamically change some images extension (from .svg to .png) only if the browser is IE.

I don't know what's the best solution :

- parse the html code with PHP
- use jQuery with something like

  $("img.svg2png").attr("src", ...);
- dealing with htaccess and rewrite rules
- other solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: Depends on how/where you are outputting the URLs?

Comment: Theoretically, you could use content negotiation (MultiViews), but at least Opera claims it prefers png to svn files in the accept header.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't do it for IE9, as it actually supports SVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not revealing many details about what you're doing, but the mod_rewrite solution (catching the `USER_AGENT` variable and checking whether it is IE, and redirecting internally to the matching `.png` file) sounds the most elegant to me, because it works sans JavaScript, and you can keep the file extension. The `.svg` extension should be meaningless as long as the right `Content-Type` header is sent.

Comment: @Pekka I have to transform my 

    <img src="img/img1.svg" class="svg2png" />

to

    <img src="img/img1.png" class="svg2png" />

I'll give a try to your solution, thanks !

Comment: @Kaaviar you're welcome. Using mod_rewrite, you wouldn't have to transform URLs. It would always be `img1.svg` but if its IE, a PNG would be served under that name.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't sound very professional. Why rely on the user agent sniffing, when you can use content negotiation. That's at least what Wikipedia does.

Comment: @mario if it's possible to get reliable results using content negotiation, great! Why not add an answer outlining how it's done? I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @Pekka: Well okay, scrape that. Even my Firefox sends a silly header. Accept:image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 - so PNG would always have precedence over SVG in Firefox. Might be possible to use qs= values with a .var typemap for Apache, but that's too much effort. So I wonder how Wikipedia does it after all.

Comment: @mario maybe they mix both approaches... Interesting. The Wikipedia Article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics doesn't go into detail on how they actually do it.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
var imageArray = $('img.svg2png').attr('src').split('.');
var newImage = imageArray[0]+'.png';

$("img.svg2png").attr("src", newImage);
```

keep in mind that this is assuming that you only have 1 period in the full src of the file (that being extention period)

to break it down, what .split('.') does is create an array of strings where the period is a delimiter.  so

```
imageArray[0] = 'imagesDir/imageName'
```

and

```
imageArray[1] = 'svg'
```

so what you are doing is reconstructing the src with the first part of the image and a new extention.

hope this helps!